# Asynchronous Http Client for Android return null

Tags: android

In my program which used Asynchronous Http Client for Android,a java.io.EOFException happed about the http get reqeust.the following is my sample code:

```
String url = http://te.3g2win.com/wordpress/?callback=?&zywxapp/content/post/82; 
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        System.out.println("request = "+ response);
    }
});
```

this url can not get the request result,and the request result is :"request = null". it works well with other urls ,such as http://www.google.com. and the Exception appears here:

```
com.temobi.mdm.net.loopjasync.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java
```

but when i use org.apache.http.client.HttpClient with this url, the request can be returned normally.

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String url = http://te.3g2win.com/wordpress/?callback=?&zywxapp/content/post/82;
```

with

```
String url = "http://te.3g2win.com/wordpress/?callback=?&zywxapp/content/post/82";
```

Comment: thanks.but this is not the real reason.it just a syntax error here.and it cannot works for me.

Comment: Response has many non-english characters so first make sure that AsyncHttpResponseHandler can handle some non-english character properly or it has some support for it.